# SQLite Selection Args in Where Clause

Tags: android, sqlite

I am sending the following query to my DBHelper class in an Android app:

```
Cursor c = null;
String tempLastName=lnameText.getText().toString();
String tempFirstName=fnameText.getText().toString();
c=myDbHelper.getProvider(tempLastName.toString(),tempFirstName.toString());
```

And in my DBHelper class for the getProvider method I have the following code:

```
public Cursor getProvider(String lname,String fname) throws SQLException {
String tempSearchStr=KEY1_LASTNAME+"='lname'"+"AND"+KEY1_FIRSTNAME+"='fname'";
String sql="Select * from ProvidersSummary Where LastName='lname' AND Where FirstName='fname'";
Cursor mCursor=myDataBase.rawQuery("Select * from ProvidersSummary Where LastName='lname' AND  FirstName='fname'",null);

if (mCursor != null) {
mCursor.moveToFirst();
}
return mCursor;
}
```

If I pass only the "lname" string, I will return a record from the DB, however, when sending both the "lname" and "fname" I do not get a record.

I'm thinking it is something with the strings, but I just can figure it out after trying about every combination.

Any help or pointers is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
public Cursor getProvider(String lname,String fname) throws SQLException {
    String tempSearchStr=KEY1_LASTNAME+"='lname'"+"AND"+KEY1_FIRSTNAME+"='fname'";
    String sql="Select * from ProvidersSummary Where LastName='lname' AND Where FirstName='fname'";
    Cursor mCursor=myDataBase.rawQuery("Select * from ProvidersSummary Where LastName='lname' AND  FirstName='fname'",null);
```

First, remove `tempSearchStr` and `sql` here. They are not used and have syntax problems.

Second, pass the parameter values to the query instead of querying for `fname` and `lname` literally. Change the query to:

```
Cursor mCursor=myDataBase.rawQuery("Select * from ProvidersSummary Where LastName=? AND  FirstName=?", new String[] { lname, fname });
```